# Is it rude to tell someone "do whatever you want"? does it mean you care less?

Tags: politeness

Would it be impolite to tell someone "do whatever you want" if you have been asked "what was the right thing to do"? does it mean you care less?

Comment: This is more of an etiquette question than an English language and usage question. Whatever else "Do whatever you want" may be taken to mean, it means that the speaker is unwilling to commit to expressing a view about the propriety of the conduct that the questioner is asking about.

Comment: It can sound standoffish and abrupt. As if to say "I don't care what you do, it's your life/choice/decision etc." A lot depends on context, your role and the intonation of your voice.

Comment: Without any context, this is a guessing game.

Comment: The words could theoretically be used erotically. So I've heard.

Answer (score 4):

My original answer (in the comments above) to this question interpreted the response "do whatever you want" as being inherently evasive: "Whatever else 'Do whatever you want' may be taken to mean, it means that the speaker is unwilling to commit to expressing a view about the propriety of the conduct that the questioner is asking about."

Returning to this question a few days later, however, I think that whether the response provides useful advice or merely avoids offering a direct opinion depends on the context in which the answer is offered, as Mari-Lou A's comment above suggests.

For example, if the question is along the lines of "Should I let Person X tell me what to do, or should I do whatever suits my fancy, or should I try to find a middle ground between those two options?" the response "Do whatever you want" advocates in favor of the second option—and cannot reasonably be interpreted as signifying that the answerer doesn't care what the questioner ends up doing.

On the other hand, if the question is something like "Should I just keep waiting and hoping that you might change your mind and decide to marry me, or should I give up all hope?" the response "Do whatever you want" indicates a terminally frigid level of indifference.

I suspect that most situations fall somewhere between those two poles, but I would guess that the instances where "Do whatever you want" is intended encouragingly and supportively are somewhat fewer than the instances where it is intended to shrug off further conversation on the question.

Comment: This is a good summary. The key is that in the first case, you're giving the person permission to do something; while in the second, you're rejecting responsibility or involvement. Giving permission is good, refusing to help is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in most cases. It's like saying "I don't care", "I don't know", "I don't have an opinion", "I give up", or "I deny any responsibility". It just shows coldness, indifference, apathy, and that you wish not to have involvement/responsibility in a scenario and don't have interest in it. It can make the person feel like you don't want to help them or just don't care. It makes a person feel bad and like you have no wish to engage with them.

There are some situations where it can show encouragement or approval, but that's not the case in most situations. Same thing with saying, "you do you", "it's your/it's not my life/business/decision/choice/etc", and others.

I always hate when people say things like that to me. If you genuinely have no opinion or don't know what to say, you can always just tell them that or refer them to someone else instead of making them feel like you don't care (even if you don't care, be nice).